# Make div width adapt automatically to contents within it

Tags: html

I have a `div` within which a `table` would lie. Now I want this `div` to have its width set automatically to the width of `table` within it.

For example:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td>World</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample</td>
      <td>Table</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I tried giving `float: left;` property to it. It works, but then it creates another problem. Whatever content is put after this div gets placed to the right of it in the empty space.

What needs to be done?

Comment: Similar question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713790/how-do-i-make-a-div-have-the-same-width-and-height-of-its-content)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to clear the float after your div by adding *style="clear: left;"* on your  consecutive element:

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <table>...</table>
</div>
<div style="clear: left;">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: can we center align this div which has float: left property ? I tried to put it in `<center>` tag but didnt work out. Also tried `align: center` in css attributes, that also didn't wat can be done ?

Comment: try to add `position:relative; right:-50%;` to your floating div.

Answer (score 18):

You are effectively attempting to change the display model of that div element, so you should change it's CSS 'display' property as follows:

```
div{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/5pPwP/) demonstrating the solution.

Answer (score 6):

This is quite new but...

If you don't want the element to become inline-block, you can do this:

```
.parent{
  width: min-content;
}
```

You have a lot of other options for configuring the width. Read more here: http://caniuse.com/#search=intrinsic

Comment: Work's like a charm

Answer (score 2):

You need to clear the float explicitly in order to not impair subsequent elements by the float. See this [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you want the div to be as wide as the table but not any wider. Since the div-element is a block element, it will always be as wide as it can be unless you give it an explicit width.
Your choice is to either add the style `display:inline` or use an inline-element like "span".